# Is it possible to play a perfect run on every floor in Wolfenstein 3D?

Tags: wolfenstein-3d

I see videos of perfect runs of Wolfenstein 3D showing up all over the place, with 100% kills, 100% treasure, and 100% secrets, but I have  yet to see a single one of them that achieves this while also finishing the floor under the par time limit.

Is this even possible? I can imagine it being done on some of the smaller floors, but can it be done for every single floor?

Specifically, I'm asking if this can be done on the hardest difficulty as well. I don't care if someone has a video of them doing it on the "Can I play, Daddy?" difficulty.

Any evidence of such a perfect run for every floor on Death Incarnate difficulty would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shortest answer to your question is simply "No".

E2-8 has a par time of 3:00 and a pushwall maze that takes up the *entire left half of the map*. There are *hundreds* of pushwalls in that level and each one takes about 2 to 3 seconds to move out of the way; even using a conservative guess, the time you'd spend waiting on pushwalls to move (2 sec x >100 secrets >= 180 seconds) would easily exceed the par time for the stage.

This doesn't take into account having to actually kill the enemies in that level (or the bosses that can appear in the pushwall maze!), either. In all likelihood, several levels can be fully cleared with all 100%s below the par time, but most definitely not *all* of them.

Comment: Excellent example! I originally assumed since you can max out the time bonus at 30,000 points, and the combined bonuses for 100% exploration total 30,000, you could only reasonably achieve one or the other. This answer definitely confirms it at least for E2-8. Thanks!